# Support for Annotation for Amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts

As supported in earlier versions is support for Annotation or drawing on the chart, and exporting it as supported formats deprecated?

Thanks,
Kalpesh

Comment: Annotations are not supported yet. There's an open issue for it on [github](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/171) you can subscribe to for updates.

Comment: thanks looking forward for that feature

Answer (score 0):

Annotation is now supported by Amcharts4. However, I noticed the annotations on a zoomable chart didn't stay with the data location.
[annotations on zoomable chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oj3X.png)